# JavaScript unexpected ReferenceError: Object key value not defined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a JavaScript Minecraft Blocklauncher mod.

```
var undo = new Array(0);
var redo = new Array(0);

function Checkpoint(FromUI) {
 if (undo === undefined) {
     undo = new Array(0);
 }
 if (undo.length == 0) {
     undo.push(new Array(0));
 }
 else if (undo[undo.length - 1].length > 0) {
  undo.push(new Array(0));
  if (undo.length > size) {
   undo.shift();
  }
 }
 redo = new Array(0);
 if (FromUI !== undefined) {
  Msg("Undo: " + undo.length + " level(s) available.  Redo stack has been cleared.");
 }
}

function SetBlock(x, y, z, id, metadata) {
 if (!Array.isArray(undo[undo.length - 1])) {
  undo[undo.length - 1] = new Array(0);
 }
 undo[undo.length - 1].push({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z, 'block': id, 'metadata': Level.getData(x, y, z)});
 setTile(x, y, z, id, metadata);
}

function Undo() {
 if (undo.length > 0) {
  var i = undo.length - 1;
  redo.push(new Array(0));
  for (var a = undo[i].length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
   redo[redo.length - 1].push({x:undo[i][a].x,
                   y:undo[i][a].y,
                   z:undo[i][a].z,
                   block:getTile(x, y, z),
                   metadata:Level.getData(x, y, z)});
   setTile(undo[i][a].x, undo[i][a].y, undo[i][a].z, undo[i][a].block, undo[i][a].metadata);
  }
  undo.pop();
  Msg("Undo successful.  " + undo.length + " undo level(s) remaining.  " + redo.length + " redo level(s) available.");
 } else {
  Msg("Nothing to undo.  " + redo.length + " redo level(s) available.");
 }
}
```

`Checkpoint()` is called once, then `SetBlock()` is called multiple times. When `undo()` is called, the error occurs.

**The erroring line is:**

`redo[redo.length - 1].push({x:undo[i][a].x,
                       y:undo[i][a].y,
                       z:undo[i][a].z,
                       block:getTile(x, y, z),
                       metadata:Level.getData(x, y, z)});`

With:

> Error occurred in script: World Editor.js
>   org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "x" is not defined.
>   (World Editor.js#1369)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(Unknown Source)
>     at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFoundError(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.name(Unknown Source)
>     at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Unknown Source)
>     at script.Undo(World Editor.js:1369)    at script.procCmd(World
>   Editor.js:451)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.ScriptManager.callScriptMethod(ScriptManager.java:288)
>     at
>   net.zhuoweizhang.mcpelauncher.ScriptManager.chatCallback(ScriptManager.java:516)

I have tried many different ways of assigning an array to each element of the `undo` array, and assigning objects with multiple properties to the array contained within the undo array element, but always get this error.

Why does this error occur, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: on which line error occurs?

Comment: As stated: `redo[redo.length - 1].push({x:undo[i][a].x, y:undo[i][a].y, z:undo[i][a].z, block:getTile(x, y, z), metadata:Level.getData(x, y, z)});`

Comment: `"x" is not defined.` seems pretty clear to me. This `x:undo[i][a].x` does not declare variable `x`, but a property.

Comment: @Slai, doesn't x get defined in `SetBlock()` in `undo[undo.length - 1].push({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z, 'block': id, 'metadata': Level.getData(x, y, z)}); setTile(x, y, z, id, metadata);`?

Comment: no .. variable declaration would have equal sign like `x = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you need to add this line:

```
function Undo() {
 if (undo.length > 0) {
  var i = undo.length - 1;
  redo.push(new Array(0));
  for (var a = undo[i].length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
   redo[redo.length - 1].push({x:undo[i][a].x,
                   y:undo[i][a].y,
                   z:undo[i][a].z,
                   block:getTile(undo[i][a].x, undo[i][a].y, undo[i][a].z),
                   metadata:Level.getData(undo[i][a].x, undo[i][a].y, undo[i][a].z)});   // <-- changed those 2 lines
   setTile(undo[i][a].x, undo[i][a].y, undo[i][a].z, undo[i][a].block, undo[i][a].metadata);
  }
  undo.pop();
  Msg("Undo successful.  " + undo.length + " undo level(s) remaining.  " + redo.length + " redo level(s) available.");
 } else {
  Msg("Nothing to undo.  " + redo.length + " redo level(s) available.");
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't x (and y, z, block and metadata). get declared when the code pushes `{'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z, 'block': id, 'metadata': Level.getData(x, y, z)}` into `undo[undo.length - 1]` in SetBlock()?

Comment: @MontyWild no, that declares the `.x` property in for example `undo[i][a].x`, but doesn't declare a variable `x`

Answer (score 0):

I was so intent on the object that I forgot to look at the functions...

```
function Undo() {
 if (undo.length > 0) {
  var i = undo.length - 1;
  redo.push(new Array(0));
  for (var a = undo[i].length - 1; a >= 0; a--) {
   redo[redo.length - 1].push({x:undo[i][a].x,
                   y:undo[i][a].y,
                   z:undo[i][a].z,
                   block:getTile(undo[i][a].x, undo[i][a].y, undo[i][a].z),
                   metadata:Level.getData(undo[i][a].x, undo[i][a].y, undo[i][a].z)});
   setTile(undo[i][a].x, undo[i][a].y, undo[i][a].z, undo[i][a].block, undo[i][a].metadata);
  }
  undo.pop();
  Msg("Undo successful.  " + undo.length + " undo level(s) remaining.  " + redo.length + " redo level(s) available.");
 } else {
  Msg("Nothing to undo.  " + redo.length + " redo level(s) available.");
 }
}
```

I needed to prefix `x`, `y` & `z` with `undo[i][a].`